# iOS Camera Programming - How to get still images Quickly In use AVCaptureVideoDataOutput and AVCaptureStillImageOutput case

Tags: objective-c, avcapturesession

I get still images in the case of AVCaptureVideoDataOutput and AVCaptureStillImageOutput，but it spends much time(2s) when I get still image with captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection,

When I just use a AVCaptureStillImageOutput, get a still image with the time of 0.5 seconds.

How can I reduce the time in the case of AVCaptureVideoDataOutput and AVCaptureStillImageOutput。

Answer (score 3):

The photo you get from **AVCaptureVideoDataOutput** is a **low quality photo**, If you want to have the same quality as photos takes with **AVCaptureStillImageOutput**, unfortunately you have no option than **waiting** for the time it takes.

*When the image quality is not a concern, try changing the session Preset with the optoions available,*

```
 //----- SET THE IMAGE QUALITY / RESOLUTION -----
 //Options:
 // AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh - Highest recording quality (varies per device)
 // AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium - Suitable for WiFi sharing (actual values may change)
 // AVCaptureSessionPresetLow - Suitable for 3G sharing (actual values may change)
 // AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480 - 640x480 VGA (check its supported before setting it)
 // AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720 - 1280x720 720p HD (check its supported before setting it)
 // AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto - Full photo resolution (not supported for video output)

 NSLog(@"Setting image quality");
[CaptureSession setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium];
```

*Changing the preset will result different processing times.*

Comment: Thank you for reply. I want to take low qualite photo get from AVCaptureVideoDataOutput, than take full resolution photo with AVCaptureStillImageOutput, But it took too much time from calling captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection to get a photo, I'll think of whether there are other ways to quickly achieve such，
Hope to get your reply again。